# Scrapy not getting titles from website

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm just starting to learn webcrawling and I am having an issue about getting the correct titles from a website. I am currently watching this guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1EFnX1UkXVU and it tells you to make this class:

```
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
   name = "craig"
   allowed_domains = ["craigslist.org"]
   start_urls = ["http://ksu.craigslist.org/search/foa"]

   def parse(self, response):
       hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
       titles = hxs.select("//p")
       for titles in titles:
          title = titles.xpath("a/text()").extract()
          link= titles.xpath("a/@href").extract()
          print title, link
```

The issue is that the link prints only a bunch of /for/###numbers###.html and the title doesn't print anything at all. I'm not sure why this is occuring. I've read through previous threads and changed a few things around but I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: look up python requests (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and beautifulsoup. You may find it a little easier to put together.

Answer (score 3):

Scrapy XPath selectors will extract what's in the HTML of that page, nothing more, nothing less, according to the XPaths you give it.

Let's look at your sample URL and its response in scrapy using `scrapy shell`, and test your XPaths (note that I'm using scrapy 1.0, and some result lines are stripped):

```
(scrapy10)paul@paul$ scrapy shell -s USER_AGENT="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.125 Safari/537.36" http://ksu.craigslist.org/search/foa
2015-06-22 19:23:26 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
...
2015-06-22 19:23:27 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2015-06-22 19:23:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://ksu.craigslist.org/search/foa> (referer: None)
...
>>> for paragraph in response.xpath('//p'):
...     print "----------"
...     print paragraph.xpath('a').extract()
...     print paragraph.xpath('a/text()').extract()
... 
----------
[u'<a href="/for/5083735342.html" class="i" data-ids="0:00G0G_gb8cQBnOWca"><span class="price">$50</span></a>']
[]
----------
[u'<a href="/for/5042795578.html" class="i" data-ids="0:00t0t_g8XHo4mq1Wb,0:01111_7GErRQg9kc9"><span class="price">$10</span></a>']
[]
----------
[u'<a href="/for/5042796585.html" class="i" data-ids="0:00W0W_kAKZ780MVd4"><span class="price">$10</span></a>']
[]
----------
[u'<a href="/for/5070157083.html" class="i" data-ids="0:00H0H_l93i9PS7WEC,0:00V0V_4HHMk6zAcvp,0:01010_586rQh4KX7Y,0:00l0l_5t6DbernooP"><span class="price">$1100</span></a>']
[]
----------
[u'<a href="/for/5083629657.html" class="i" data-ids="0:01111_7ccUivz24cL"><span class="price">$2</span></a>']
[]
----------
[u'<a href="/for/5083317838.html" class="i"><span class="price">$275</span></a>']
[]
----------
[u'<a href="/for/5056913265.html" class="i" data-ids="0:00J0J_jAZGd05f59U"><span class="price">$25</span></a>']
[]
----------
[u'<a href="/for/5083138728.html" class="i" data-ids="0:00q0q_80N4SDtfsmz"><span class="price">$40</span></a>']
[]
----------
[]
[]
```

When selecting `a` children elements of `p` paragraphs (like you do), and calling `.extract()` on each, you can see the HTML of each link.
What you notice is that these tags do not have (direct) child text elements (which is what you're selecting with `a/text()`)

The "text" part you're after (I think) is inside a `span` child element.

You have different options here:

- use `a//text()` to select descendant text elements of all `a` elements, and not only children text
- use `string(a)` to tell XPath engine to give you the text representation of the first `a` element

For the 2nd option, you'll get this (some lines stripped):

```
>>> for paragraph in response.xpath('//p'):
...     print "----------"
...     for a in paragraph.xpath('a'):
...         print(a.xpath('@href').extract_first(), a.xpath('string(.)').extract_first())
... 
...
----------
(u'/for/5042796585.html', u'$10')
----------
(u'/for/5070157083.html', u'$1100')
----------
(u'/for/5083629657.html', u'$2')
----------
(u'/for/5083317838.html', u'$275')
----------
(u'/for/5056913265.html', u'$25')
----------
(u'/for/5083138728.html', u'$40')
----------
>>>
```

Notice that here I'm using Scrapy 1.0's handy [`.extract_first()` method](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html) for selectors.

If you need absolute URLs, you can use [Scrapy 1.0's `.urljoin()` method](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html?#scrapy.http.Response.urljoin) on the `Response` object:

```
>>> for paragraph in response.xpath('//p'):
...     print "----------"
...     for a in paragraph.xpath('a'):
...         print(response.urljoin(a.xpath('@href').extract_first()), a.xpath('string(.)').extract_first())
... 
----------
(u'http://ksu.craigslist.org/for/5070157083.html', u'$1100')
----------
(u'http://ksu.craigslist.org/for/5083629657.html', u'$2')
----------
(u'http://ksu.craigslist.org/for/5083317838.html', u'$275')
----------
(u'http://ksu.craigslist.org/for/5056913265.html', u'$25')
----------
(u'http://ksu.craigslist.org/for/5083138728.html', u'$40')
----------
>>>
```